# Threading Bitmap Decoding & assigning Bitmap to an ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin.android, xamarin, threadpool

The code below does not show the image, if I remove the thread it works but loading time is increased. How do I fix this?

Activity:

```
_imgFoo = new ImageView(this);
//layoutparams are set

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (o => {
    using (var bmp = ImageResizer.DecodeSampledBitmapFromResource (Resources, 
    Resource.Drawable.exampleimage, width, height)) {
        RunOnUiThread (() => _imgFoo.SetImageBitmap (bmp));
        bmp.Dispose ();
    }
});
```

Image Resizer Class:

```
public static Bitmap DecodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    var options = new BitmapFactory.Options {
        InJustDecodeBounds = true,
    };
    using (var dispose = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(res, resId, options)) {
    }
    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.InSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask...

A instruction how it works you find on

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

important, read the 4 subthemes too.

Lukas